# Why isn't string an IReadOnlyList<char>?

Tags: c#

C#'s string already implements IEnumerable, and it has an indexer and a well-defined length, so why not support the new interface?

is it lack of time, or was the decision made for other reasons?

Comment: You'd need to ask Anders....